# Flutter extra error information for production logging

Tags: flutter

I cannot seem to get the information on the offending widget or class when i am catching an unhandled error.

Is there actually a way to get that kind of data?

```
            FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
                print('Will log here ${errorDetails.exception.toString()}');
                
                //load the hivebox 
                final userInfoBox = Hive.box('userInfoBox');
                
                //get the value
                bool logMode = userInfoBox.get('logModeEnabled');
                
                //log event if activated
                if (logMode == true) {
                    MyLogger.error('Unhandled exception - ${errorDetails.exception.toString()}');
                    MyLogger.error('Unhandled exception - ${errorDetails.context.toString()}');
                    MyLogger.error('Unhandled exception - ${errorDetails.informationCollector.toString()}');
                    MyLogger.error('Unhandled exception - ${errorDetails.library.toString()}');
                    MyLogger.error('Unhandled exception - ${errorDetails.stackFilter.toString()}');
                    MyLogger.error('Unhandled exception - ${errorDetails.stack.toString()}');
                }
                
                locator<TelemetryRepository>().processTelemetryData(
                    loggingCode: '00010',
                    incomingPayload: {
                        'error': errorDetails.exception.toString(),
                        'context': errorDetails.context.toString(),
                        'informationCollector': errorDetails.informationCollector.toString(),
                        'library': errorDetails.library.toString(),
                        'stackFilter': errorDetails.stackFilter.toString(),
                        'stackTrace': errorDetails.stack.toString(),
                    },
                );
                
            };
```

All i am getting back is this which is not detailed enough to fix display error and critical errors:

```
2023-12-22 13:12:50.959948 ERROR [main:<fn>] DataLogType.NONE -> Unhandled exception - A RenderFlex overflowed by 1472 pixels on the right.  

2023-12-22 13:12:50.969715 ERROR [main:<fn>] DataLogType.NONE -> Unhandled exception - during layout  

2023-12-22 13:12:50.978558 ERROR [main:<fn>] DataLogType.NONE -> Unhandled exception - Closure: () => List<DiagnosticsNode>  

2023-12-22 13:12:50.988957 ERROR [main:<fn>] DataLogType.NONE -> Unhandled exception - rendering library  

2023-12-22 13:12:50.997862 ERROR [main:<fn>] DataLogType.NONE -> Unhandled exception - null  

2023-12-22 13:12:51.006724 ERROR [main:<fn>] DataLogType.NONE -> Unhandled exception - null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview/)
It will record your all unhandled and handled exceptions and crashes.
and you can monitor all exceptions on firebase console.

```
 await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
  error, 
  stackTrace,
  reason: 'a fatal error',
  // Pass in 'fatal' argument
  fatal: true
);
```

Comment: Nothing i can build myself?